# show separate drop down list for hour and minute in extjs 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, time, extjs3

I am working on an extjs 3.1.1 application. Now I have a timefield that user select time from that and save this time but this timefield drop down list is very long and hard to find desired time. so I want to put separate drop down lists for hour and minute. can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

here is my code which i am using for date and time field.you can define format of time .

i>for date:

```
  new Ext.form.DateField({
                id : 'scheduleDate',
                fieldLabel : 'Date',
                format : 'd-M-Y',
                editable:false,
                minValue : new Date(),
                allowBlank : false

            })
```

ii>for time:

```
new Ext.form.TimeField({
            id : 'scheduleTime',
            fieldLabel : 'Time',
            allowBlank : false,
            editable:false,
            format : 'H:i',
            increment: 1
        })
```