# Strange datefield behavior

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a form with a datefield field.

http://jsfiddle.net/NRNjh/3/

Code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',

        items: [{
            id:'startdate',
            xtype:'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            format: 'd.m.Y H:m',
            name: 'email'

        }],
        buttons: [{
            id: 'saveBtn',
            itemId: 'saveBtn',
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function() {

                var df = this.up('form').down('#startdate');
                var d = df.getValue();               

                alert('minutes: ' + d.getMinutes() + ' hours: ' + d.getHours());               

            }
        }]
    });
});
```

The strange thing is e=when I pick a date from the datepicker. The hours are set to 00 and minutes to 09. I would understand that the minutes value would be set to 00 but why 09 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"m" is for Month, you have it in "d.m.Y" so you'll see it repeat or change based on the month.

You want "d.m.Y H:i"

Reference: [show separate drop down list for hour and minute in extjs 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673147/show-separate-drop-down-list-for-hour-and-minute-in-extjs-3-1-1)

Answer (score 1):

"format" is what you need to change

```
    items: [{
        id:'startdate',
        xtype:'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Email',
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        name: 'email'

    }],
```